# Como usar o Jquery UI com o Jquery 3.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Estou utilizando o `Jquery UI 1.12` com o `Jquery 3.1.1` e utilizando as funções `draggable` e `resizable`.

Entretanto, sempre quando vou testar não funciona pois dá a exceção

```
$(...).find(...).andSelf is not a function
```

Eu pesquisei e vi que foi tirado esta `andSelf` e colocado o `addBack` no `jQuery` mais atual, mas aí não funciona o `jQuery UI`, só com o `Jquery 1.12`. Mas o site que estou mexendo já tinha importado o `jQuery 3.1.1` e não posso mexer pois pode dar problema em alguma função que alguém tenha feito anteriormente.

O que fazer para solucionar este problema?

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei o [jQuery UI 1.12.1](https://blog.jqueryui.com/2016/09/jquery-ui-1-12-1/) é compatível com o jQuery 3.1.0, talvez uma possível alternativa seria migrar para ele, visto que foram poucas [modificações](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/compare/3.1.0...3.1.1), **talvez** não interfira em funções existentes (vale o teste).

Answer (score 0):

O `.andSelf()` foi descontinuado no jQuery 1.8, detalhes:

- https://api.jquery.com/andself/

Use no lugar dele [`addBack`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/)

Se for um bug no jQuery ui tente fazer o upgrade para o 1.12.1 (versão atual estável), se não der, tente simplesmente um *hack* (gambiarra):

```
$.fn.andSelf = function() {
     return this.addBack.apply(this, arguments);
};
```